# 8P8C non standard connector?

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan, rj-45

A short backstory to clarify the issue.

Not long ago I bought a used home router from CISCO, model EA6300V1 to increase the speed of my local network up to 1 Gbps.

The local network works fine after I changed the cable terminators to use all eight wires, because previously only six wires were connecting to the LAN as 100 Mbps only uses six wires.

***Please note***, that I only had to replace the plugs to make sure that all the wires are being used, but I didn't have to use any new types of plugs.

For the WAN port on the router, I didn't have to replace the plugs, as my Internet connection is 100 Mbps only.

However an issue arose with the WAN connection, as it I was loosing connection to the Internet every so often, and seemingly at random, as one day the connection would work perfectly fine, and on another day the connection would get lost, and then get working back again all on its own throughout the day.

*Upon closer inspection, **I was able to figure out the cause of the issue**, as the WAN and LAN sockets on the router appear to be ever so slightly different!*

So while the LAN sockets can maintain firm contact with the plugs that I'm currently using, the WAN socket doesn't do so.

It seems that the only way to make the plugs that I use to work with the WAN socket on the router is to physically tilt the plug so that it maintains proper contact with the socket.

***To fix this issue*** I had to extend the existing Internet cable with a store-bought cable, which does maintain the proper contact with the socket in the router.

***Question #1 is: why would the sockets be different?***

***Question #2 is: is there a naming standard that I can use to differentiate between these two types of sockets so that I can buy the right kind of the plug next time?***

I will be attaching the respective pictures of the sockets, and the plugs. **As you'll be able to see, sockets obviously have different dimensions, and *shape*.**

[Router sockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mssJm.jpg)

[Store-bought cable that works fine with the WAN socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdmu2.jpg),
[same store-bought cable from different angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsZJ1.jpg).

[Internet plug view1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgpsH.jpg),
[Internet plug view2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9eTs.jpg),
[Internet plug view3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdTNW.jpg).

Additionally I provide the information that's printed on the store-bought cable.

> BELKIN COMPONENTS CATEGORY 5e PATCH CABLE #R7J304 VERIFIED (UL) CAT 5e
> 4PR 24AWG TYPE CM OR MP E129760 CSA TYPE PCC FT4 LL80671 ETL VERIFIED
> TO TIA/EIA 568A ISO/IEC 11801 [www.belkin.com](http://www.belkin.com)

Comment: 100 Mbps Ethernet only uses four wires (two pairs); "six" makes me suspect yours was once wired for Ethernet + telephone.

Comment: It wasn't, it's just that I was laying those cables myself, and because I didn't know what wires were necessary I used a sample plug that was cut off from somewhere. Maybe that plug WAS once used as Ethernet + telephone at some point as you've said it, but in my case it was just Ethernet.

Comment: If it had the innermost pair in use it was most likely telephone. (Original Ethernet twisted-pair wiring was specifically designed to go along with existing analog telephone installations, which traditionally used the inner pair of a RJ11, so Ethernet used the outer pair + one additional pair on the side.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question #1 is: why would the sockets be different?

The router manufacturer bought them as separate parts from different suppliers. It's common to use a "4x socket" unit for the switched LAN ports, while the fifth port is its own part – and was most likely made either by a different manufacturer and/or at a different time.

> Question #2 is: is there a naming standard that I can use to differentiate between these two types of sockets so that I can buy the right kind of the plug next time?

No, they're both the same type of socket.

The connector type just has some pretty lax tolerances, and in particular it's the cheap *plugs* (and their latch clips) that vary a lot, so unfortunately you may just end up with combinations of plug+socket that "click" into place even before the pins make contact (as well as combinations that you spend two minutes trying to *unplug* the thing, on the other hand).

Comment: So out of curiosity why would manufacturers use different sockets for WAN? Is it possible that those sockets come packaged with some sort of electric equipment within the socket assembly that's specific for WAN?

Comment: No, they just get whatever component is the most readily available. There is no electrical difference because even the 'WAN' Ethernet port still connects to local equipment (your modem or ONT); copper Ethernet isn't meant to go anywhere further than that. (Although there _is_ some electrical equipment – the 'magnetics' – that is mandatory for every Ethernet port, whether WAN or not, and it may be either separate or integrated into the socket, and that may influence their purchasing decisions, although it is still functionally identical for both WAN and LAN ports.)

Comment: But the thing is, the WAN port on my router has different dimensions not only when it comes to connecting to plugs, but it's also different in size inside the router itself, which tells me that the manufacturer had to update the design of the PCB. Take this image for example: https://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/linksys_ea6300_inside1.jpg
Wouldn't this make such a replacement not cost efficient, rather than using the same socket for every port?

Comment: Two 2-socket parts still may be more cost-efficient than four 1-socket parts (or more available for purchase in the amounts needed). They wouldn't have had to _update_ anything if they designed the PCB with these parts in mind from the beginning (after all, it's not the first router model Cisco made).

Comment: Sounds plausible, but there's another issue. I find it hard to believe that the manufacturers of the sockets would allow for such lax tolerances. Wouldn't manufacturers want to make their products compatible with each other, to sell more of them?

Comment: Well, yes, but people will buy even products that are just barely compatible if it's cheap. I mean, both of the ports work fine with a factory made cable – my feeling is that your crimp-on plugs are the ones that are only mostly compatible (i.e. tested with one random port and that's it), but cheap enough that everyone still buys them by the bag.